# Free Mac OS X MySQL GUI

Tags: macos, mysql, database, gui

I'm looking for a good GUI app like Heidi SQL on windows for mac os x, snow leopard specifically. It can support more DBs than MySQL but needs to at least that. I'd like to be able to manipulate DBs, schemes etc... through it easily.

Answer (score 10):

I use: http://www.sequelpro.com/

also, how about squirrel?
http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yeah, **SequelPro** rules. Well-designed and stable.

Comment: +1 for SquirrelSQL You'll need to get the JDBC drivers to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), it's actually fairly nice.

There's a feature list on Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench#Features

Answer (score 1):

Not taking away from the 2 fine clients that were offered, you can just use the fact you already have Apache installed on your machine, and use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse and [Eclipse SQL Explorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/). You'll need to configure with the JDBC drivers.

[Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/) is free for non-commercial use.

I use [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) as others have listed.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)

   free and open source but you can donate it's developer.
2. [Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

   which is produced by Oracle, And it supports windows, Mac OS X, Linux.
3. Navicat

   prodeced by PremiumSoft ™ CyberTech Ltd.

   free try for 30 days

   support windows, Mac OS X, Linux